# Will this resonant IR2153 circuit work?

Tags: transformer, diodes, design, mains, microchip

Will this work?

Proposed principle of operation:

1. R-C oscillator starts resonation of coil and capacitor.
2. The R-C oscillator is overriden by the induced voltage.
3. The frequency is dynamically adjusted.

(I'm sorry that the circuit is not straight- hand drawn never is.[image: schematic]

Comment: What if you get a 500V Power line transient from say a motor shut off? or a 3kV transient?   get my point? it is better to use active PFC setup then Buck step down.nOtherthan that, your input surge current depends on Vp/ESR(cap+diodes) will be huge

Comment: Completely off track. This is for flybacks/SSTC's. also X1 does not go to pin 2, but to pin 3. Power line filtering- I do not care.

Comment: I was concerned about damage to your design, not ability to generate SSTC. It is trivial to generate 50kV with good magnetic autotransformer, but what are your specs for J discharge or corona?

Comment: Understood. But, I wanted to make this as an improvement to fixed frequency R-C network typically used with IR2153 chip.

Comment: stability of f depends entirely on ripple voltage across Vcc pin 1 to 4 as well as RC tolerances. You can simulate this with Falstad adding ESR to C and C ratio and internal Zener ESR.

Comment: Of course. Question was about if this would work as described.